# Create dynamic form from vector or array

Tags: java, arrays, swing

First of all, I'm new in java.
I would like to generate forms dynamically based on Arrays, I was able to generate the fields, but I do not know how to read them, I couldn't find something like text field index or something.
So basically i'm asking how to read values from a TextField component that has no reference.
JTextField myText = new JTextField() vs new JTextField(), added to a panel
Below is a simple code example, any idea is welcomed.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame{
    private JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    private JButton btn = new JButton("Read Data");

    public Test(){
        super("Dynamic Form");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Declare the Array with fields
        String[] fList = new String[3];
        fList[0] = "id";
        fList[1] = "firstName";
        fList[2] = "lastName";

        //Iterate fields array and add elements
        for(int i = 0; i<fList.length; i++){
            add(new JLabel(fList[i]));
            add(new JTextField("field: "+fList[i]));
        }

        add(p1);
        add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
                    String id = "id field value is: "; // + some code to get actual text field value
                    String firstName = "firstName field value is: "; // + some code to get actual text field value
                    String lastName = "lastName field value is: "; // + some code to get actual text field value

                    System.out.println(id+ " " + firstName + " " + lastName);
                }
            }
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: You de realize that although vectors and arrays can each hold a collection of objects, they are quite different data structures, right?  I ask because the title mentioned vectors but the body only arrays.

Comment: Actually in the end i will use an ArrayList of objects but for the question itself i tried to keep it simple. Feedback is welcomed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store references to those text fields somewhere.

```
List<JTextField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
```

...

```
for(int i = 0; i<fList.length; i++){
        JTextField field= new JTextField("field: "+fList[i]);
        add(new JLabel(fList[i]));
        add(field);
        fields.add(field);
}
```

Now you can access them from your fields list:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
    String id = "id field value is: " + fields.get(0).getText(); 
    String firstName = "firstName field value is: " + fields.get(1).getText(); 
    String lastName = "lastName field value is: " + fields.get(2).getText(); 

    System.out.println(id+ " " + firstName + " " + lastName);
}
```

Comment: It makes perfect sens to me now. thanks.